# Adding authentication to static Azure Website

Tags: authentication, azure, azure-web-app-service

We have an Azure Website hosting a static site (just some HTML, CSS, Javascript), which then communicates with our Azure Mobile Services by AJAX calls.

We would like to add some very simple authentication to this site (just a static username/password will be sufficient).

Please recommend the easiest way to do this.

Or may be there is some better option for serving static content, other then Azure Websites?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

A very simple form of authentication with a static username and password can be achieved by leveraging ASP.NET's authentication and authorization, integrated with IIS as described in this article: [Apply ASP.NET Authentication and Authorization Rules to Static Content with IIS 7.0's Integrated Pipeline Feature](https://web.archive.org/web/20211020135904/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/122408-1.aspx).

Se [this sample GitHub project](https://github.com/fernandoacorreia/StaticAuthSample) for an example. The relevant pieces of code are this Web.config file that you should place in the root directory (which would be public):

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
    <system.web>
        <compilation debug="false" />
        <authentication mode="Forms">
            <forms>
                <credentials passwordFormat="Clear">
                    <user name="Alice" password="secret" />
                </credentials>
            </forms>
        </authentication>
        <!-- Unless specified in a sub-folder's Web.config file, 
             any user can access any resource in the site -->
        <authorization>
            <allow users="*" />
        </authorization>
    </system.web>
    <system.webServer>
        <modules>
            <remove name="FormsAuthenticationModule" />
            <add name="FormsAuthenticationModule" type="System.Web.Security.FormsAuthenticationModule" />            
            <remove name="UrlAuthorization" />
            <add name="UrlAuthorization" type="System.Web.Security.UrlAuthorizationModule" />
        </modules>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

And this Web.config file that you could place in a subdirectory (which would be restricted):

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
    <system.web>
        <!-- Anonymous users are denied access to this folder (and its subfolders) -->
        <authorization>
            <deny users="?" />
        </authorization>
    </system.web>
</configuration>
```

You also need a [Login.aspx](https://github.com/fernandoacorreia/StaticAuthSample/blob/master/Login.aspx) file with the HTML form and server-side authentication logic. See the Login.aspx in the sample project for an example.

This way you would be able to host both public files at root level and private files at subdirectories. If you want to protect even the root level, just adjust the authorization rules accordingly.

For documentation on configuration options see these MSDN pages:

- [authorization Element (ASP.NET Settings Schema)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/8d82143t%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)
- [allow Element for authorization (ASP.NET Settings Schema)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/acsd09b0%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)
- [deny Element for authorization (ASP.NET Settings Schema)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/8aeskccd%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

Comment: It does work. Thanks Fernando. 
Just one more question, if you don't mind. I would like to protect all the files even at root level. So I changed first Web.config (which is at root level) like this: `<allow users="Alice" />`. Now when I go to http://mysite.azurewebsites.net/index.html it redirects to Login.aspx, so it works properly. But, when I go to http://mysite.azurewebsites.net/ (without specifying index.html) it shows index.html but without any styles or images. 
I never worked with IIS and .NET, so please can you give a quick fix to this, too? 
Thanks.

Comment: We have fixed this problem by adding `<deny users="?" />`, `<authorization>` section. Thank you once more, Fernando, for your answer.

Comment: That's right, that configuration blocks anonymous users. Sorry I wasn't able to answer sooner. I've updated my answer with links to additional documentation on configuration options.

Comment: @FernandoCorreia I tried this but i am directly been redirected to the private.html it doesnt ask for username and password. I hosted this as it is in azure static website. Please help me what i am doing wrong.

Comment: @GiorgiKandelaki  I tried this but i am directly been redirected to the private.html it doesnt ask for username and password. I hosted this as it is in azure static website. Please help me what i am doing wrong.

Answer (score 4):

This is an old question that's been previously answered, but if you're looking for the easiest possible solution that requires no code or config changes, you can use Azure Websites Authentication / Authorization (disclaimer, I helped build this feature).  Here are some links:

Blog Post:
http://azure.microsoft.com/blog/2014/11/13/azure-websites-authentication-authorization/

Demo Video:
http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/videos/azure-websites-easy-authentication-and-authorization-with-chris-gillum/

EDIT:
And here is a more recent blog post describing how you can use social providers (Twitter, Facebook, Google, Microsoft Accounts) in addition to the default Azure AD: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/announcing-app-service-authentication-authorization/

Comment: Chris, I can't seem to find a way to only protect a sub-folder of static html using deferred authentication.  I see that I can put a special login link to the content from an unprotected part of the site, but how would I protect against accessing the html file directly?

Comment: @SergioL you can use URL authorization rules for that: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/appserviceteam/2016/11/17/url-authorization-rules/

Comment: just curious -would you use this for a serious financial web site?