# Password Protecting an Azure Website not just via Web App Form

Tags: azure

I have a beta web application which I want to password protect. I would like to lock down the whole folder as one does in IIS which then force the username/password popup. I have done this with my previous shared host on IIS7. However now that I have migrated the site to Azure Websites, I cannot find a method to do this in Azure.

All feedback, that I have read, on this seem to say that it is forms authentication only. Is this true, or is there a way to password protect a complete Azure Website?

Thanks,

EDIT:

I do authenticate within the web app, since this is a requirement of the web app, but I want a simple password protection over all of this that was external to the application.

Comment: are you talking about Basic Authentication for the web-site? This looks relevant: http://www.devbridge.com/articles/basic-authentication-for-windows-azure-websites  and this http://stackoverflow.com/a/17621867/809357

Comment: Yes I think that is what I am talking about. Basically a user goes to the URL, and then they should get a popup authentication window for the whole website. So it does not matter if certain web application logins are a bit weak. This articles look useful. Currently working my way through.

Comment: That is called Basic Authentications. You'll find a stack of articles about that on Azure in Google. Correct key-words are the key to success! -)

Comment: Just been playing with this a little more. While the above approach looks good and very simple, I am unsure how it would co-exist with my currently used membership services. What I am looking for is an overarching password for the whole application, so when one successfully authenticates past this login screen one would then be present with the application membership services login page. This is what would happen if one were password protecting via IIS.

Comment: Found the answer, "HttpAuthModule", on nuget. Marvellous little utility.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use [HttpAuthModule](https://www.nuget.org/packages/HttpAuthModule/) nuget.

You can [install Nuget package with Visual Studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/install-use-packages-visual-studio). Right click on the project for the website you want to secure. Click "Manage NuGet packages". In the browse tab in the search box, search for the phrase "HttpAuthModule". Select the resulting module and click install. This should install the package and make some changes to your web.config file.

Open the web.config and then edit the settings, in particular change the "value" for the "credentials" parameter to be a "username:password;" of your choosing. Now run your site and you should be prompted to enter a username and password.

Comment: Seconded! This is a great tool in that it leaves the rest of your membership authentication code well alone, plays nicely with the OWIN Identity provider as well (as in, it operates a level above) - perfect for securing a staging site.

Comment: Can you expand your answer a little more to explain how you use a Nuget package on Azure Websites?

Comment: Per Doug's request: Assuming you are using Visual Studio, right click on the project for the website you want to secure. Click "Manage NuGet packages". In the browse tab in the search box, search for the phrase "HttpAuthModule". Select the resulting module and click install. This should install the package and make some changes to your web.config file. Open the web.config and then edit the settings, in particular change the "value" for the "credentials" parameter to be a "username:password;" of your choosing. Now run your site and you should be prompted to enter  a username and password.

Answer (score 6):

Another option which is now available is to use the new Azure Websites Authentication / Authorization feature.  This enables you to quickly and easily add Azure Active Directory login to your entire website without any code changes. It also works with site slots, so you can have a beta version of your site in a staging slot which is protected by a login page, and a production version which is exposed publicly.

Blog Post: http://azure.microsoft.com/blog/2014/11/13/azure-websites-authentication-authorization/

Demo Video: http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/videos/azure-websites-easy-authentication-and-authorization-with-chris-gillum/

Comment: I found that this still interfered with the .NET authentication logic within my site. For instance, calls to Request.IsAuthenticated and User.Identity.IsAuthenticated were impacted. This option should work for a site that doesn't run it's own authentication logic, or where you want to use the same authentication source for accessing the site (i.e. the user logs in as the exact user that they would log in as if accessing the site in production). I went with the HttpAuthModule that SamJolly refers to. It took about 30 seconds to setup and was exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: We are experiencing the exact same issue. I'd love to hear from Chris Gillum on if its possible to have Authentication (with Azure AD and other providers on the Portal) that doesn't interfere with the underlying application.

Comment: @ChrisMatthews or Svenkle, can you clarify what the impact is? It's probably something that can be easily fixed - but I want to make sure I understand the scenario.

Comment: @ChrisGillum, I can't speak for everyone - but in our case, we want to use Azure AD as an authentication gateway to prevent the public from browsing our development sites. ie. You have a guest login in the Azure AD therefore you can browse to the website.
The current implementation is causing the application to assume that the principal set from the AD login flow is the same as you would use in the application.

Comment: Example
John browses to http://mydevapp.azurewebsites.net.
John is presented with Azure AD login flow page.
John enters his email and password john@comany.com.au.
John is then presented with the homepage of mydevapp - a page that in Production is public but for corporate security reasons cannot be publicly accessible in a development environment.

Comment: Scenario #1 – Current
John then decides to browse to the administrator portion of http://mydevapp.azurewebsites.net. The mydevapp application doesn’t know who john@company.com.au is and John is presented with an error. This is due to the fact the mydevapp application is relying on a principal that was altered by the AD login flow.

Comment: Scenario #2 – Requested state
John then decides to browse to the administrator portion of http://mydevapp.azurewebsites.net and is presented with the mydevapp application login screen. John enters a set of credentials to the custom application form and is granted access to the administrator portion of the mydevapp system. The current principal remains in the control of the application rather than the AD login flow.

Comment: @Svenkle Got it - thanks for the explanation, it makes perfect sense. It sounds like we need to look into a switch which disables the behavior of assigning the current thread principal since it prevents you from also using your own custom identities. FWIW, this should only be an issue w/ASP.NET 4.x. Other platforms, including ASP.NET Core, are not affected by this behavior.

Comment: @Svenkle Great clean explanation of the issue. Saved me a lot of typing. Now I can just go with "WhatHeSaid".

Comment: @ChrisGillum that's great! How long would it take to see this functionality enabled - even if we needed to add custom app settings and the like? We are keen to get this in prior to our platform launch.

Comment: @Svenkle It would take about a month to get it out to production, worldwide. Would that work for you or is that too far out?

Comment: @ChrisGillum that's a reasonable timeframe. We are also happy to get on-board with preview functionality in order to get access earlier.

Comment: @ChrisGillum any news on the rollout? Is it looking to be ready by ~25th September?

Comment: @Svenkle unfortunately it's not going to make it in time due to some other high-pri work that needs to be done for the MS Ignite conference. I've opened a tracking item for this in an unofficial GitHub repo here if you'd like to follow up: https://github.com/cgillum/easyauth/issues/2

Answer (score 0):

This may also be of value if you want a very light weight Forms auth solution:

- https://web.archive.org/web/20211020135904/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/122408-1.aspx
- source code example: https://github.com/fernandoacorreia/StaticAuthSample
- use sha1 password https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/da0adyye(v=vs.100).aspx
- create sha1 of password http://www.sha1-online.com/

bonus: force serving over https: https://selimgueler.azurewebsites.net/how-to-configure-azure-web-sites/